# How can I say "I would like to know how to do something"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage

I am practicing to compose an inquiry. I read that saying "I would like to~" is させていただきます. There are similar questions about "to know how to do something" but expressing your intent to know is what I am struggling with.

For example, I can think of saying how to make a payment again as「…どうやって再度支払いをするか知っていますか？」. But I think させていただきます won't fit in that context.

Comment: Can you write down what you are trying to say in complete English sentences?

Comment: I assume from context that you intend to *ask* the recipient, not merely communicate "I would like to know this, so I am going to do my own research and find out".

Comment: I hate people who say させていただきます for "I would like to ..."

Comment: In English, making an inquiry sometimes begins with "I would like to know~" to sound more polite. For example: "I would like to know how to use this product". In this context, the speaker did not know what to do and wanted to ask for information.

About させていただきます, I did not intend to use it in this context since I also read that it was meant to use by the speaker as having given the opportunity to do something. So that is out of the question. However, I do not know other ways to say it the way I meant to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

させていただきます does work as a translation of *I would like to*, but only in some cases. E.g. I would like to start the presentation = プレゼンを始めさせていただきます.

It is a humble form for *I will do something*, literally something like *Let me take the honor of -ing* and won't fit in case of asking how to.

Polite way of asking include

- どうやって再度支払するか**ご存じですか** (*Perhaps do you know...*)
- どうやって再度支払するか**教えていただけますか** (*Would you tell me...*)
- どうやって再度支払するか**教えてください** (*Please tell me...*)

The basic pattern should be {どうやって, どのように}...{するか、すればいいか}{ご存じですか、教えてください、教えていただけますか}. In normal conversations どうやって...するか教えてください is usually polite enough.